# How to use a Result when there is no success value to return from a function?

Tags: error-handling, rust

To define a function with void return, my code goes like the following:

```
trait Handler {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: String) -> Result<()> {
        println!("on_message: {}", msg);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The compiler tell me this is wrong because a `Result` should always have 2 parameters:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 1
 --> src/lib.rs:2:46
  |
2 |     fn on_message(&mut self, msg: String) -> Result<()> {
  |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^ expected 2 type arguments
```

This confuses me. How should I define a function when I don't care about its return value?

Comment: You should still add an error as second argument, since there may still be an error returned from your function.

Comment: void is simply `()` so you could just `on_message(&mut self, msg: String) -> ()` or just `on_message(&mut self, msg: String)` but a function should already return something in general

Comment: @Stargateur Obviously, the OP needs some error handling. `Result<(), ErrorType>` is fine for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need error handling, then there is no need to use a `Result`:

```
fn on_message(&mut self, msg: String) { 
    // ... 
}
```

If you need to handle errors, but don't have a meaningful "success" value, then you can say that the success type is `()`, but you still need to say what the error type is:

```
fn on_message(&mut self, msg: String) -> Result<(), MyError> {
    // ...
}
```

Where I put `MyError`, you could use a built-in error like `io::Error`, a custom error struct or enum, or any other type such as `String`. It could even be `()`, making your return type `Result<(), ()>`, which would let users of your function know if it was successful or not, without providing any information about either the successful outcome or the possible error. At that point, you might consider using an `Option<()>` or even just a `bool`, which carry the same amount of information.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is trying to tell you that `Result` takes two type parameters, i.e. `Result<(), ()>`. Here's a working version:

```
trait Handler {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: String) -> Result<(), ()> {
        println!("on_message: {}", msg);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this answer bring that the existing answer, which already suggests using `Result<(), ()>`, does not?